# Prevent HTML5 video changing Chrome's icon and title

Tags: html, google-chrome, html5-video, favicon

I have a website that has an HTML5 video embedded in it.  Anytime Chrome visits a site with such a video, however, it overwrites the page's `<title>` and shortcut icon to show pause / play symbols and the elapsed time of the video.  Anyway to prevent this from happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Cannot see this behavior at my place (using Chrome 17 on Windows), can you add how you embed and handle the `<video>`. Are you using some kind of fullscreen mode?

Comment: @m90 Although I want to change this on a site that I'm developing, this behavior happens on any site with HTML5 video that I visit in Chrome (18.0.1025.142 m).  For example, playing the video on this page will do it: [W3 Schools HTML5 Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/default.asp).

Comment: Won't be of too much help for you, but even your example won't trigger the beahvior in Chrome 17. Let's wait for the update then. **EDIT**: Just noticed that I have been updated to 18 tonight and I still don't see it (18.0.1025.142 m on Windows Vista).

Comment: I have the latest Chrome and I don't see the icons you mention. I think you might have a Chrome Extension that does that. Can you check that out?

Comment: Ahhhh! Thanks @Francisc - you nailed it.  I had [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ojpfpnnblmkgkpobiamilejllmkfmflg) extension buried deep among other extensions.  Completely over looked that.  If you submit is as an answer I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the latest Chrome and I don't see the icons you mention. I think you might have a Chrome Extension that does that. Can you check that out?